# Get children from kv file before it is applied

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a kv file or string for example

```
KV = '''
<BoxLayout>
    Label
    Label
    Button
    MyButton
'''
```

and I would like to get children list like

```
['Label', 'Label', 'Button', 'MyButton']
```

before this kv string is applied (before Label, Button and MyButton instances created).
How to do this?
Can I use kivy.lang.Parser for that?
I suppose kivy Parser does something like that, but I didn’t figure out how to use it - the documentation is scarce on this topic, and the source code looks confusing.

I'm planning to create a widget event, named something like on_kv_pre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Builder.match_rule()` for your situation:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<BoxLayout>
    Label
    Label
    Button
    MyButton
''')

ret = Builder.match_rule_name('BoxLayout')
for child in ret[0].children:
    print(child.name)
```

May be a bit more complicated for real rules, but maybe this can get you started.

Comment: I need to do this before loading kv string (before Label, Button and MyButton instances created)

Comment: The children (and the `BoxLayout`) are not created until you do a `BoxLayout()` in python. The rule in your `KV` string just sets up a rule to be applied when a `BoxLayout` is created. The `Builder.load_string()` does not create any instances for rules enclosed by `<>`.

Comment: And, if needed, you can `unload` the `kv` string using `Builder.unload_file()`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_string).